# Problem to put two small buttons in row - one is always stretched

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put two small buttons, one on left side ( info ) and other on right side ( exit ).
I tried with this

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="#aaaaaaaa">
    <TableRow>

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
                android:src="@drawable/info"
                android:layout_width="32px"
                android:layout_height="32px"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="3dip"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnExit"
                android:src="@drawable/error"
                android:layout_width="32px"
                android:layout_height="32px"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

but I got this 
[image] and error button is strected and I don't need that. Can anyone say me what I have done wrong ?

Comment: RelativeLayout seems to be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple using RelativeLayout

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:src="@drawable/info" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/exit"
  android:src="@drawable/erro"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [stretchColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3astretchColumns).

Remove `android:stretchColumns="1"` and it shouldn't stretch. You are telling it to stretch the second column, 0 being the first column.

Answer (score 1):

in tag tablelayout use android:layout_width="wrap_content" in place of fill_parent.